# How to change region for competitive Rocket League tournaments?

Tags: rocket-league

In Rocket League, when I play Tournaments it says I am playing in the region "NORTH AMERICA".

I am from Europe though and playing with 120ms ping is no fun.

When playing in normal mode, I can change the region setting from a dropdown right from the playlist view.

Yet for the tournaments I am unable to find it. Where do I change the region for competitive tournaments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the main menu, hit settings. In the Gameplay tab, at the very bottom you can change the TOURNAMENT SCHEDULE REGION.

Keep in mind that you have to wait 24 hours after playing a tournament before you are allowed to change the region.

Also be aware that your changed setting will be locked for 24 hours.

So you cannot change the regions on the fly.

[image: Screenshot of Gameplay tab with configuration highlighted]